# Column 'IC NUMBER' does not belong to table in winform

Tags: c#, winforms, datatable, datacolumncollection

I'm trying to access a data column in a `datatable` to get its value but i keep getting the same error that the IC NUMBER column does not belong to this table! on this line

```
ic[j] = Form1.dt.Rows[i]["IC NUMBER"].ToString();
```

when i debug the application i can see the column is there :

[image]

and when i use this code :

```
ic[j] = Form1.dt.Rows[i][5].ToString();
```

it works fine but i need to use the columns name since there will be more or less column each and every time user import a new file. what is wrong with my code?

Comment: There is a space at the end of `"IC NUMBER "`, in your string you are missing that space, so try `ic[j] = Form1.dt.Rows[i]["IC NUMBER "].ToString();`

Comment: WOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOW....i could never have seen that . thanks a lot man

Comment: @Habib if you don't mind, write the same thing as answer so i can mark it as answered

Comment: @Ali, this is a  typo, and unlikely to help future visitors, that is why I have voted to close this question as a simple typographical mistake.